# position is returning undefined when setting current location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using google address auto complete api to pre populate address. I am setting the geolocation on session. That works fine but for the argument of the circle object, the "position" I get a javascript error saying position is undefined. How should I get around this?

```
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation && !sessionStorage.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      sessionStorage.geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
    });
  }
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: sessionStorage.geolocation,
    radius: position.coords.accuracy
  });
  autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very easy. Not sure why I didn't think about this before. First of..the sessionStorage can only store strings and I am passing an object. So 1: that is incorrect. 2: position is not in scope of the var circle because it is an argument to a callback function. The solution is

```
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation && !sessionStorage.geolocation) {
    sessionStorage.geolocation = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      window.geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      window.o = {
        center: window.geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      }
    });
  }
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle(window.o);
  autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
}
```